# Individual Username from a Database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, web

I have a database running and I'm currently printing out in a website, in a "php block" the usernames of the database. I achieved it with this

```
if ($db_handle) {

print "Database ISSSSS Found ";


$SQL = "SELECT * FROM `database.com`.`users`";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);

//print $result;

while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {

    print $db_field['username'] . "<BR>";
}

mysql_close($db_handle);

}
```

However this gives me a giant string of all the users (I currently have 4). How do I make it so its just the individual user accessing their profile through the website

Comment: `WHERE user_column = X`

Comment: By using a WHERE clause in your SQL query

Answer (score 0):

Typically, when someone logs in, you would store non sensitive information about the user in the session. This way, you can get to it quickly without needing to make database calls on every page. For instance, if you wanted to show their username in the pages header, you would always have their username handy to do so. Then, when they go to view their profile, you can use that username you stored as part of your SQL WHERE clause to pull in information pertaining only to that specific user.

Comment: That sounds very useful and the proper way to do things for sure. Part of my website design is I want the users name displayed somewhere like "Hello, ___". How would you go about storing this stuff when they log in

Comment: by adding it to $_SESSION. Lets say you captured their username, and stored it in a variable called 'userName', you could then just do $_SESSION['user'] = userName.  Then where you want to print their user name you would just 'echo $_SESSION['user']'  and it would print their username.

Comment: That sounds perfect. The only problem is the way my files are set up (I'm using Filezilla to access the database) is I don't know where I would put that. I'm assuming that would be a type of global variable. The register.html file is huge and its included in register.php but I don't know where register.php is included (I didn't make the original files)

Comment: $_SESSION is a 'superglobal', so long as you are on at least version 4.1 of php, it exists automatically, and can be accessed in all scopes. Basically, you can get anything stored in it from anywhere in your php, at any time.

Comment: I just went to take a look and verify what I told you, (shame on my for verifying after I posted instead of before) and came across this good page for it [check it out](http://www.php.net//manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) Fortunately my information was accurate, but that is a better source for information on $_SESSION if you want to read it.

Comment: Okay thats something new. I figured I would store it when they login, but the login files are in html. If I create php blocks, 1) can I access the data, 2) will I still have access to it after the login. I'm new to making websites and databases in general

Comment: right in the middle of your html you can just put '<?php '...' ?> replacing ... with whatever php code you need. So to insert the username at the top you would have something like  <p>Hello, <?php echo $_SESSION['user'] ?></p>

Answer (score 0):

Use `WHERE username = 'yourusername'` in your SQL query.

That shall fix your problem

Comment: I added it so it says now 
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM `gamerlookup_com`.`users` WHERE username = excal"; 

where excal is the username. However when I try to access the "email" parameter, it gives me a blank

Comment: The field is case-sensitive, are you sure you have written it correctly? Does other fields work? Try echoing the Username which you got from SQL.

Comment: I tried to add an echo $result['email'] before the while loop but that prints out nothing. I realize it's not going into the while loop with the help of a print statement.

Comment: Try `var_dump($result)` before the while loop. If you get an empty array or null, you probably have written it wrong.

Comment: 'var_dump($result)' gave me bool(false) as an output for some reason

Comment: Hmm, strange. Try using MySQLi instead of MySQL, that may work.

Comment: Oh, never mind, I figured it out, you need to use apostrophes in your query, so `WHERE username = 'username'`

Comment: Yes that was it. I thought it needed apostrophes but you're the expert lol. thank you. I got exactly what I wanted. Now just one last thing. So I accessed the data in a php block inside an html file. How do I access the data from the php to use in the html part. I basically want to do this http://puu.sh/9mbrn/4be706c0b2.png

Comment: Just write your html and when you need the data just begin your php tags again and print it out. And use sessions so you can keep your users logged in.

Comment: Well the whole point of me accessing the php in the html was so I can use the placeholders from the picture I showed you to display the users previous information when they edit their profile. Since placeholder is a html thing, I don't think the php tags would work unless there was some way to store the data globally

Comment: Yes it will work, `<input type='text' placeholder='<?php echo $data; ?>'>`